# How do I exclude one category from a blog page on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, categories

I have two categories of posts. I only want one to show up on a blog page. The page is not the home page. I tried using this code in the codex:

```
<?php
if ( is_page('page_slug') ) {
    query_posts( 'cat=-(category id)' );
}
?>
```

to no avail. I also tried creating a new template for the page, then using

```
<?php
if ( is_page_template('new_blog') ) {
    query_posts( 'cat=-(category id)' );
}
?>
```

on the index.php, and still nothing. Maybe I'm putting the code in the wrong place? Can anyone offer any advice on how I might achieve this?

EDIT:

Here is the functions.php file:

```
<?php

include_once get_template_directory() . '/functions/blackbird-functions.php';
$functions_path = get_template_directory() . '/functions/';
/* These files build out the options interface.  Likely won't need to edit these. */
require_once ($functions_path . 'admin-functions.php');  // Custom functions and plugins
require_once ($functions_path . 'admin-interface.php');  // Admin Interfaces (options,framework, seo)
/* These files build out the theme specific options and associated functions. */
require_once ($functions_path . 'theme-options.php');   // Options panel settings and custom settings
require_once ($functions_path . 'shortcodes.php');
?>
<?php

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Styles Enqueue */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function blackbird_add_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style('shortcodes', get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/shortcode.css", '', '', 'all');
}

add_action('init', 'blackbird_add_stylesheet');
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* jQuery Enqueue */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function blackbird_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('blackbird-ddsmoothmenu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ddsmoothmenu.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('blckbird-flex-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('blackbird-testimonial', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slides.min.jquery.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('blackbird-prettyphoto', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('blackbird-validate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.validate.min.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('blackbird-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'));
    } elseif (is_admin()) {

    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blackbird_wp_enqueue_scripts');
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Custom Jqueries Enqueue */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function blackbird_custom_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script('mobile-menu', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/mobile-menu.js", array('jquery'));
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'blackbird_custom_jquery');
//Front Page Rename
$get_status = blackbird_get_option('re_nm');
$get_file_ac = get_template_directory() . '/front-page.php';
$get_file_dl = get_template_directory() . '/front-page-hold.php';
//True Part
if ($get_status === 'off' && file_exists($get_file_ac)) {
    rename("$get_file_ac", "$get_file_dl");
}
//False Part
if ($get_status === 'on' && file_exists($get_file_dl)) {
    rename("$get_file_dl", "$get_file_ac");
}

//
function blackbird_get_option($name) {
    $options = get_option('blackbird_options');
    if (isset($options[$name]))
        return $options[$name];
}

//
function blackbird_update_option($name, $value) {
    $options = get_option('blackbird_options');
    $options[$name] = $value;
    return update_option('blackbird_options', $options);
}

//
function blackbird_delete_option($name) {
    $options = get_option('blackbird_options');
    unset($options[$name]);
    return update_option('blackbird_options', $options);
}

//Enqueue comment thread js
function blackbird_enqueue_scripts() {
    if (is_singular() and get_site_option('thread_comments')) {
        wp_print_scripts('comment-reply');
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blackbird_enqueue_scripts');
?>

<?php
add_action('init','posts_of_one_cat');
function posts_of_one_cat() {
if ( is_page('26')  ) {
    query_posts( 'cat=-12' ); // 3 is id of your category you want to exclude
  // do anything here 
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_posts()](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/exclude-category-from-get_posts) is desirable as an option.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'category' => '-(category id)',
?>

<?php
    $postslist = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($postslist as $post) :
     setup_postdata($post);
?>
```

Comment: Do I put that in the functions.php? or the blog page template I'm using? I'm sorry, I'm really new to all of this, but I've been put in charge of a website and I'm trying to learn very quickly.

Comment: No problem! We all had to start off at some point too (I'm definitely still learning). This will go in the template you are using. From within the `foreach` loop you will be able to do things like get/output `$post` data like for example: `echo $post->ID`, `$slug = $post->slug`. To spit out the whole post, to see what you can access and how to access it, just put `var_dump($post)` in the `foreach` loop, and go from there. Happy coding, and godspeed.

Comment: I finally figured it out! Thanks for your help. I feel like this has given me a much stronger feel for messing around in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

On index.php this code will not execute as index.php is homepage add this code in functions.php in some function

something like ...

```
<?php
add_action('init','posts_of_one_cat');
function posts_of_one_cat() {
if ( is_page('your blog page id here')  ) {
    query_posts( 'cat=-3' ); // 3 is id of your category you want to exclude
  // do anything here 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I did that, and the whole site went down. It said "unexpected < in functions.php" Should this be straight jquery?

Comment: that was syntax error maybe you did place `<?php` php opening tags in another `<?php` opening tags

Comment: Aha, sorry for the stupid error. I put the code in and I'm still not seeing any effects. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: make a custom template for your blogpage, assign that template to your page and do all your custom coding there i would advice